# How to create a generic retrofit service

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to make a generic retrofit post request but I am getting "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to coe.nativeandroid.data.repository.Repository$LoginRequest"

My current request looks like this:

```
@POST
suspend fun <T>postRequest(
   @Url url: String,
   @Body body: Any? = null,
   @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>? = null
): T
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for **kotlin**:

Try this:

```
interface IApiService {


    @GET("{url}")
    suspend fun getRequest(
        @Path(value = "url", encoded = true) path: String,
        @QueryMap hashMap: Map<String, String>
    ): Maybe<Response<ResponseBody>>

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("{url}")
    suspend fun postRequest(
        @Path(value = "url", encoded = true) path: String,
        @FieldMap hashMap: Map<String, String>
    ): Maybe<Response<ResponseBody>>

    @Multipart
    @Headers("Content-Type:multipart/form-data")
    @POST("{url}")
    suspend fun sendDocuments(
        @Path(value = "url", encoded = true) path: String,
        @PartMap partMap: Map<String, RequestBody>
    ): Maybe<Response<ResponseBody>>


    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("{url}")
    suspend fun postRequestForRaw(
        @Path(value = "url", encoded = true) path: String,
        @Body requestBody: RequestBody
    ): Maybe<Response<ResponseBody>>

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but all I had to add was the Reposnse, so I had to return this : Response<T>

Comment: So what's the problem! Generic response!